# Python pyserial use a lot of CPU for simple task on Celery

Tags: python, celery, pyserial, rs485

I'm using Pyserial inside a Celery worker to write every *150ms* a packet of max 20 bytes on the serial

Literally the celery worker does nothing except send data on the serial with `ser.write(packet)` with `ser = serial.Serial(COM, 38400, timeout=0.1)`

#### Celery worker

```
@shared_task(bind=True)
def start_serial_acquisition(self, idObj, porta_COM):
   ser = serial.Serial(COM, 38400, timeout=0.1)
   packer = b'\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80'
   time_start = time.monotonic()
   time_stop = time.monotonic()
   while True:
      time_stop = time.monotonic()
      if(time_stop - time_start > 0.149)
         ser.write(packet)
         time_start = time.monotonic()
```

The main issue is that this simple process, takes an entire core of my two core CPU with the result 50% of the CPU is used just to send data on the serial. The specs of my PC are

```
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy
```

I'm using Python 3.10 and the latest version of pyserial and celery v5.3.0

When I stop writing on the serial, the CPU basically goes IDLE with a consumption between 1-2%

I can't find the issue as, I would like to optimize it. I'm using a [USB - RS485 converter](https://it.farnell.com/ftdi/usb-rs485-we-1800-bt/cavo-usb-rs485-convertitore-seriale/dp/1740357?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIl_nD5dfCgAMVCN7tCh2GkQhmEAQYAyABEgLtAfD_BwE&mckv=_dc%7Cpcrid%7C%7Cplid%7C%7Ckword%7C%7Cmatch%7C%7Cslid%7C%7Cproduct%7C1740357%7Cpgrid%7C%7Cptaid%7C&CMP=KNC-GIT-GEN-SHOPPING-PMAX-Low-Roas-Short-Title-Test-21-Dec-22&gross_price=true) as serial to communicate data

Comment: `Literally the celery worker does nothing except send data on the serial with ser.write(packet) with ser = serial.Serial(COM, 38400, timeout=0.1)` that doesn't help, post full code so people can actually verify what's doing what.

Comment: @Daviid added code. The issue seems to be there's no `time.sleep()`. Adding a `time.sleep(0.05)`, for istance, brought back CPU usage to almost IDLE while sending. I'm gonna run other tests to be sure tho

Comment: You are writing data in a tight loop `while True:`.

Comment: If you want to write every 150ms you should add `time.sleep(0.15)`  inside the while loop

Comment: @Daviid even waiting 150ms measuring with `time.monotonic()` gives me the issue. As suggested by @Alberto and under testing by me, it seems to be the super fast `while` cycle that has no `time.sleep()`

Comment: Of course it's fast, your timeout on the serial is 0.1 so when writing it'll take at MOST 100 milliseconds and at fastest depends on your CPU. Try `while True: i=0 print(i) i += 1` and see how fast that goes.

Comment: Even a `sleep.time(0.01)` inside the `while`, just before the `time_stop = ...` should reduce the cpu usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not surprised that the task consumes 100% CPU because the while loop runs forever measuring time, calculating `time_stop - time_start` and checking whether it is greater than 0.149. You should have something like this instead:

```
   while True:
       ser.write(packet)
       time.sleep(0.15)
```